# "can only iterate over an array"

Tags: java, arraylist

**Link to Marks.txt file I was using for Student records for I/O:** [enter link description here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/kksq6qvb1zllfpc/marks_test_no_empty_strings.txt)

I have a **Student** class(contains 1 int studentID, and 6 assignment float scores) that is supposed to be filling another class called **CourseSection** (is just an ArrayList of Student objects), which is an ArrayList, with Student Objects.

So each Student Object should fill up the ArrayList called **CourseSection** after the data is read from a Marks.txt file.

I'm trying to write the search() method so it prompts the user for input of an StudentID, and then this int ID is used to traverse the ArrayList of Student objects until it .getID() == ID (the one the user input). THEN, it needs to display the corresponding students 6 assignment scores(floats). I'm getting a

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable
```

The error is coming from right after the for loop where is says "course2". Is java not reading this as an ArrayList? It's supposed to be an ArrayList of Student objects correct? because you can see I create the CourseSection object called "course2" first, then I read from the file Marks.txt and assign "course2" to equal this CourseSection.loadFrom method (which the method is returning a CourseSection object).

```
public static void search(){

        BufferedReader aFile;

        CourseSection course2 = new CourseSection(); //creates course object which is ArrayList of Student objects

        aFile = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("marks_test_no_empty_strings.txt"));
         course2 = CourseSection.loadFrom(aFile); // reads .txt into course ArrayList

        Scanner scanner =  new Scanner(System.in);
        int id;
        boolean foundStudent = true;


        System.out.print("Enter the Student's ID: ");
        id = enterID();

       for(Student s : course2) {
            if(s.getID() == id) {
                s.getA1();
                s.getA2();
                s.getA3();
                s.getA4();
                s.getMidterm();
                s.getFinalExam();
            }
            else
                System.out.println("ID not found!!!");
        }
 }
```

and the **CourseSection** class if it helps:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.io.*;

public class CourseSection {
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Student> students;

   /**
   * Initializes the ArrayList<Student>.
   */ 
  public CourseSection(String n)
  {
    name = n;
    students = new ArrayList<Student>();
  }

  public CourseSection()
  {
    students = new ArrayList<Student>();
  }

  /**
   * Will add a new student to the ArrayList.
   * @param s A Student object.
   */
  public void addStudent(Student s){
    students.add(s);
  }

  /**
   * Removes the selected student from the ArrayList.
   * @param s A Student object.
   */
  public void removeStudent(Student s){ 
    Iterator studentIterator = students.iterator();

    while(studentIterator.hasNext()){
      if(studentIterator.next() == s)
        studentIterator.remove();
    }
  }


  /**
   * Lists all the information for each student in the course section. 
   */
  public void listStudents(){

    for(Student s: students){
      System.out.println(s);  
    }  
  }

  /**
   * Reads aFile except for the header and continuously creates new student objects 
   * for a new CourseSection.
   * @param aFile File to read from.
   * @return CourseSection New CourseSection read from aFile
   */
  public static CourseSection loadFrom(BufferedReader aFile) throws IOException{
      //String line = aFile.readLine();
    CourseSection course = new CourseSection(aFile.readLine()); 
    aFile.readLine(); // skips line
    while (aFile.ready()) //read until no more available (i.e., not ready)
    { 

        course.addStudent(Student.loadFromST(aFile)); //read & add the student
        }

    return course;
  }

}
```

This is the file I use to test the **loadFrom** methods in the **Student** class, and to test **loadFrom** in the **CourseSection** class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class loadTester {

    private static void studentLoadTest() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader  file1;
        Student student1; // student object
        //String line;

        file1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("marks_test_no_empty_strings.txt"));

        file1.readLine(); // skips 1st line
        file1.readLine(); // skips 2nd line

        /*
        while(file1.ready())
        {
            System.out.println(file1.readLine());
        }
        */

       /* while((line = aFile.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        */
       student1 = Student.loadFromST(file1); // using String Split
       System.out.println(student1); // This method individually parses it

       //file1.close();
    }

     private static void courseLoadTest() throws IOException {

            //String line;
         //CourseSection course = new CourseSection();

            BufferedReader aFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("marks_test_no_empty_strings.txt"));

            CourseSection course = CourseSection.loadFrom(aFile);
           // course.loadFrom(aFile);
            course.listStudents(); // this outputs the STUDENT OBJECTS IN THE ARRAY LIST!

            //course = CourseSection.loadFrom(aFile);
            //aFile.close();
        }

     public static void search(){

            BufferedReader aFile;

            CourseSection course2 = new CourseSection(); //creates course object which is ArrayList of Student objects

            aFile = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("marks_test_no_empty_strings.txt"));
             course2 = CourseSection.loadFrom(aFile); // reads .txt into course ArrayList

            Scanner scanner =  new Scanner(System.in);
            int id;
            boolean foundStudent = true;


            System.out.print("Enter the Student's ID: ");
            id = enterID();

           for(Student s : course2) {
                if(s.getID() == id) {
                    s.getA1();
                    s.getA2();
                    s.getA3();
                    s.getA4();
                    s.getMidterm();
                    s.getFinalExam();
                }
                else
                    System.out.println("ID not found!!!");
            }
     }

            public static int enterID(){

                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                int id = 0;

                try{
                  System.out.print("Enter the student's ID: ");
                  id = scanner.nextInt();
                }catch(InputMismatchException e){
                  System.out.println("Error: InputMismatchException");
                  id = enterID();
                }

                return id;
              }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Testing Student Object I/O Stream:");
        studentLoadTest(); // testing to see if it outputs 1 Student Object per line
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Testing CourseSection creating ArrayList of Student Objects I/O Stream:");
        courseLoadTest(); // this should output the Entire marks.txt file as an ArrayList of Student objects
        search();
    }
}
```

Comment: `CourseSection` is neither an array, nor a list, nor an iterable. That's why. You probably intended to loop over student records?

Comment: This seems to be the problem: ` for(Student s : course2) `.  Q: Is "course2" an "array" or an "iterable"?  SUGGESTION: maybe your "course" has an array of "students", and maybe THAT'S what you want to "iterate" over?  Show us "class CourseSection".

Comment: Show the implementation of `CourseSection`.

Comment: OK, I added the CourseSection class code if that helps. @ErnestKiwele I thought CourseSection was an ArrayList, because at the top code u can see me make an CourseSection object called "course2" and I FILL this ArrayList up with Student records. I have a tester file that I was testing that show the output and the ArrayList being populated with Student objects.

Comment: Yes "course2" is supposed to be an ArrayList of "Student" objects @paulsm4 I posted the CourseSection class at the top of the question now and I can post the Student class too if need be

Comment: Maybe it's "supposed to be an ArrayList of Student objects" ... but your code makes it a class, with a MEMBER that's an ArrayList of student objects?   One possible solution: make students `public`, and change your loop to `for (Student s: course2.students) {}`?

Answer (score 0):

`course2` is not iterable (CourseSection does not implements Iterable).

To iterate over `course2`'s students, add a getter into CourseSection class :

```
public List<Student> getStudents() {
    return this.students;
}
```

and iterate over it with

```
for(Student s : course2.getStudents()) {

}
```

Comment: How do I know whether to use an regular for loop, enhanced for loop, or ITERATOR for my arraylist called CourseSection course2, which contains Student objects (from the class Student)?  Any why isn't course2 itterable???? isn't it an ArrayList? I'm so confused :(

Comment: You could use regular for loop, enhanced for loop, or an iterator on a list. course2 is not a list but course2.getStudents is.In your case course2 is not a list but holds a list of students.

Comment: OK I see its working but just printing out a bunch of garbage from the for loop, thank you for your help so much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `CourseSection` class is not iterable or an array. You can use it like that if you made this change:

```
public class CourseSection implements Iterable<Student> {

    //adding the following method:
    @Override
    public Iterator<Student> iterator() {
        return this.students.iterator();
    }
```

You can also iterate directly over students by changing the calling code:

```
//You must add the getStudents() getter in CourseSection
for(Student s : course2.getStudents()) {

}
```

Comment: do you know how the code syntax under the for loop using the getter? I tried s.getID() but that didn't seem to work and course2.getStudents().s.getID() didn't work either

Comment: @reflexez If your `students` field was declared as `Student[]`, then you could still loop over it directly, exactly as in the last example.

Comment: OK I see its working but just printing out a bunch of garbage from the for loop, thank you for your help so much!

Answer (score 0):

The CourseSection class is not a Array or list sot it won't compile try like this

CourseSection  class:

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Iterator;
  import java.io.*;
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class CourseSection {
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Student> students;

    /**
     * Initializes the ArrayList<Student>.
     */
    public CourseSection(String n)
    {
      name = n;
      students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    }

    public CourseSection()
    {
      students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    }

    /**
     * Will add a new student to the ArrayList.
     * @param s A Student object.
     */
    public void addStudent(Student s){
      students.add(s);
    }

    /**
     * Removes the selected student from the ArrayList.
     * @param s A Student object.
     */
    public void removeStudent(Student s){
      Iterator studentIterator = students.iterator();

      while(studentIterator.hasNext()){
        if(studentIterator.next() == s)
          studentIterator.remove();
      }
    }


    /**
     * Lists all the information for each student in the course section. 
     */
    public void listStudents(){

      for(Student s: students){
        System.out.println(s);
      }
    }

    public ArrayList<Student> getStudents()
    {
      return students;
    }

    /**
     * Reads aFile except for the header and continuously creates new student objects 
     * for a new CourseSection.
     * @param aFile File to read from.
     * @return CourseSection New CourseSection read from aFile
     */
    public static CourseSection loadFrom(BufferedReader aFile) throws IOException{
      //String line = aFile.readLine();
      CourseSection course = new CourseSection(aFile.readLine());
      aFile.readLine(); // skips line
      while (aFile.ready()) //read until no more available (i.e., not ready)
      {

        course.addStudent(Student.loadFromST(aFile)); //read & add the student
      }

      return course;
    }

  }
```

search method:

```
    public static void search(){

      BufferedReader aFile;

      CourseSection course2 = new CourseSection(); //creates course object which is ArrayList of Student objects

      aFile = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("marks_test_no_empty_strings.txt"));
      course2 = CourseSection.loadFrom(aFile); // reads .txt into course ArrayList

      Scanner scanner =  new Scanner(System.in);
      int id;
      boolean foundStudent = true;


      System.out.print("Enter the Student's ID: ");
      id = enterID();

      for(Student s : course2.getStudents()) {
        if(s.getID() == id) {
          s.getA1();
          s.getA2();
          s.getA3();
          s.getA4();
          s.getMidterm();
          s.getFinalExam();
        }
        else
          System.out.println("ID not found!!!");
      }
    }
```

**Student class**

```
public class Student {
  private int ID;
  private float a1;
  private float a2;
  private float a3;
  private float a4;
  private float midterm;
  private float finalExam;


  /**
   * The Default constructor is used to intialize all instance variables 
   * in the class to zero.
   */
  Student(){
    ID = 0;
    a1 = 0.0f;
    a2 = 0.0f;
    a3 = 0.0f;
    a4 = 0.0f;
    midterm = 0.0f;
    finalExam = 0.0f;
  }

  Student(int id, float a1, float a2, float a3, float a4, float midterm, float finalExam) {
    ID = id;
    this.a1 = a1;
    this.a2 = a2;
    this.a3 = a3;
    this.a4 = a4;
    this.midterm = midterm;
    this.finalExam = finalExam;
  }

//Set methods for all instance variables of Student 
  public void setID(int newID)
  { 
      ID = newID; 
  }

  public void setA1(float newA1)
  { 
      a1 = newA1; 
  }
  public void setA2(float newA2)
  { 
      a2 = newA2; 
  }
  public void setA3(float newA3)
  { 
      a3 = newA3; 
  }
  public void setA4(float newA4)
  { 
      a4 = newA4; 
  }

  public void setMidterm(float newMidterm) // Typo was here for Mideterm
  { 
    midterm = newMidterm; 
  } 

  public void setFinalGrade(float newFinal)
  { 
     finalExam = newFinal; 
  }

  //Get methods for instance variables of Student
  public int getID()
  {
      return ID; 
  }
  public float getA1()
  { 
      return a1; 
  } 
  public float getA2()
  { 
      return a2; 
      }
  public float getA3()
  { 
      return a3; 
  }
  public float getA4()
  { 
      return a4; 
  }
  public float getMidterm()
  { 
      return midterm; 
  }
  public float getFinalExam()
  { 
      return finalExam; 
  }


  /**
   * Prints all instance variables as a string.
   * @return A string representing the student.
   */
  public String toString(){
    return(ID + ": " + a1 + " " + a2 + " " + a3 + " " + a4 + " " + midterm + " " + finalExam);
  }


  /**
   * Will read from the linked file which will create and return a new Student object.
   * @param aFile File to read from.
   * @return A new Student object read from a line of the file.
 * @throws IOException 
 * @throws NumberFormatException 
   */


  //using StringTokenizer
  public static Student loadFromST(BufferedReader aFile) throws IOException {
    Student newStudent = new Student();
    //int i = 0;
    //String zero = "0";

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(aFile.readLine()," ");

    //while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        //if(st.nextToken().isEmpty())
         //zero = st.nextToken();
            //else {
    newStudent.ID = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    newStudent.a1 = Float.parseFloat(st.nextToken());
    newStudent.a2 = Float.parseFloat(st.nextToken());
    newStudent.a3 = Float.parseFloat(st.nextToken());
    newStudent.a4 = Float.parseFloat(st.nextToken());
    newStudent.midterm = Float.parseFloat(st.nextToken());
    newStudent.finalExam = Float.parseFloat(st.nextToken());
    //i++;
            //}
   // }
    return (newStudent);
  } 


  //using Split String
  /*
  public static Student loadFromSS(BufferedReader aFile) throws java.io.IOException {
      Student newStudent = new Student();
      String[] words = aFile.readLine().split(" "); // can't split for anything bigger than 1 space

      //for(int i = 0; i <= words.length; i++) {
        // if(words[i].isEmpty()) 
        // words[i] = "0";
        // } 

      newStudent.ID = Integer.parseInt(words[0]);
      newStudent.a1 = Float.parseFloat(words[1]);
      newStudent.a2 =  Float.parseFloat(words[2]);
      newStudent.a3 = Float.parseFloat(words[3]);
      newStudent.a4 = Float.parseFloat(words[4]);
      newStudent.midterm = Float.parseFloat(words[5]);
      newStudent.finalExam = Float.parseFloat(words[6]);

  return newStudent;
}*/

}
```

Comment: do you know how the code syntax under the for loop using the getter? I tried s.getID() but that didn't seem to work and course2.getStudents().s.getID() didn't work either

Comment: if  s.getID() not working it is issue in your Student class so add you student class to the question to check the problems in student class

Comment: added Student.java class to question

Comment: OK I see its working but just printing out a bunch of garbage from the for loop, thank you for your help so much!

Comment: @reflexez I cannot see student class you added anyway you find the solution. :)